# JSON string object to Dataframe in Pyspark

Tags: python, pyspark, azure-databricks

I am trying to convert JSON string stored in variable into spark dataframe without specifying column names, because I have a big number of different tables, so it has to be dynamically.
I managed to do it with sc.parallelize, but since I'm working in databricks and we are moving to Unity Catalog, I had to create Shared Access cluster, and sc.parallelize and some other libraries are not working.

I have a JSON string stored in variable that looks something like this, but originally it has much more values:

```
value_json = [{'id': '00043b01-c002-4df6-b453-8d7cd043e1a1', 'classification': None, 'createdDateTime': '2018-08-02T17:04:48Z', 'proxyAddresses': ['SMTP:Atividades789@softwareone.onmicrosoft.com', 'SPO:SPO_4e3b75d6-716f-40c3-8b59-3b474c59a9f8@SPO_[REDACTED]'], 'creationOptions': ['ExchangeProvisioningFlags:481']}, {'id': '00086d95-a5ac-4ad7-b81c-4c1561c49cb1', 'classification': None, 'createdDateTime': '2018-06-18T15:27:24Z', 'proxyAddresses': ['SMTP:Atividades789@softwareone.onmicrosoft.com', 'SPO:SPO_4e3b75d6-716f-40c3-8b59-3b474c59a9f8@SPO_[REDACTED]'], 'creationOptions': []}]
```

As I already mentioned, I managed to do it with this, but I need another solution, probably with pyspark

```
import json
df = sc.parallelize(value_json).map(lambda x: json.dumps(x))
df2 = spark.read.json(df)
display(df2)
```

Result:

| classification | createdDateTime |  |
| --- | --- | --- |
| null | 2018-06-18T15:27:24Z | 00086d95-a5ac-4ad7-b81c-4c1561c49cb1 |
| null | 2018-08-02T17:04:48Z | 00043b01-c002-4df6-b453-8d7cd043e1a1 |

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pyspark: JSON to Pyspark dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75955276/pyspark-json-to-pyspark-dataframe)

Comment: @Zero This works the same as my first solution, but I can't use "spark.sparkContext.parallelize", because it's not allowed with Shared Compute Cluster. I also can't specify column names, because I have more than 50 tables, so it has to recognize column names automatically.
This is the error message that I get: py4j.security.Py4JSecurityException: Method public org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDD org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.createRDDFromTrustedPath(java.lang.String,int) is not whitelisted on class class org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

Comment: @DileeprajnarayanThumula, yes, it's Azure Databricks.

Comment: are you able to import json package on your cluster?

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can do it.
Using Pandas creating Pyspark data frame:

```
import pandas as pd

value_json = [{'id': '00043b01-c002-4df6-b453-8d7cd043e1a1', 'classification': None, 'createdDateTime': '2018-08-02T17:04:48Z', 'proxyAddresses': ['SMTP:Atividades789@softwareone.onmicrosoft.com', 'SPO:SPO_4e3b75d6-716f-40c3-8b59-3b474c59a9f8@SPO_[REDACTED]'], 'creationOptions': ['ExchangeProvisioningFlags:481']}, {'id': '00086d95-a5ac-4ad7-b81c-4c1561c49cb1', 'classification': None, 'createdDateTime': '2018-06-18T15:27:24Z', 'proxyAddresses': ['SMTP:Atividades789@softwareone.onmicrosoft.com', 'SPO:SPO_4e3b75d6-716f-40c3-8b59-3b474c59a9f8@SPO_[REDACTED]'], 'creationOptions': []}]

dt = pd.DataFrame(value_json)

sp_df = spark.createDataFrame(dt)
display(sp_df)
```

[image]

As you said you are getting Error:error: ValueError: Some of types cannot be determined after inferring

You can try the below approach also

```
import pandas as pd
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, StringType, ArrayType

spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()

value_json = [{'id': '00043b01-c002-4df6-b453-8d7cd043e1a1', 'classification': None, 'createdDateTime': '2018-08-02T17:04:48Z', 'proxyAddresses': ['SMTP:Atividades789@softwareone.onmicrosoft.com', 'SPO:SPO_4e3b75d6-716f-40c3-8b59-3b474c59a9f8@SPO_[REDACTED]'], 'creationOptions': ['ExchangeProvisioningFlags:481']}, {'id': '00086d95-a5ac-4ad7-b81c-4c1561c49cb1', 'classification': None, 'createdDateTime': '2018-06-18T15:27:24Z', 'proxyAddresses': ['SMTP:Atividades789@softwareone.onmicrosoft.com', 'SPO:SPO_4e3b75d6-716f-40c3-8b59-3b474c59a9f8@SPO_[REDACTED]'], 'creationOptions': []}]


schema = StructType([
    StructField("id", StringType(), True),
    StructField("classification", StringType(), True),
    StructField("createdDateTime", StringType(), True),
    StructField("proxyAddresses", ArrayType(StringType()), True),
    StructField("creationOptions", ArrayType(StringType()), True)
])


dt = pd.DataFrame(value_json)

sp_df = spark.createDataFrame(dt, schema=schema)

sp_df.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for a reply, but this is not working for me, the same as other solutions that I've tried.
I get an error: ValueError: Some of types cannot be determined after inferring
From what I understood, values None and [] should be handled somehow, because spark dataframe is not accepting them

Comment: @Flip Jankovic I have updated the solution with another approach.
Hope this may help you.
Let me know if it helped.

Comment: I already mentioned that I can't specify schema, because I will have more than tables with different schemas.